# Is there a way to export all the images of my tweening effect in Flash?

Tags: 2d, flash, image, tweening

i'm using Flash to create the animation of my character in 2D (i'm just beginning). Is it possible to make a tween effect of a character, and then **automatically export all the images/frames**?

So far, it's a bit fastidious : i create my tweening effect, then i put a keyframe for each frame i want to copy and paste, then i select the movieclips and shapes and copy and paste them into another flash document, i position those clips at the exact same location as the previous image, then i erase the previous image and export the image... For 30 frames! Is there any faster way?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Take a look at the [Grapefrukt Exporter](https://github.com/grapefrukt/grapefrukt-export) library.

Comment: hi Functastic, i imported grapfrukt-export.swc, and added the few lines as in the video. I also created a movieclip "test", and another movieClip "testSheet", but when i launch the project, i've got an error 1065 : variable testSheet not defined, and Maintimeline not defined...? do you how i could fix it? Thanks

Comment: I don't know. Maybe ask on the grapefrukt exporter github issue tracker, or at:
http://prototyprally.com/introducing-the-grapefrukt-asset-exporter/